# Updating Dictionaries from Dataframe Very Slow in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to read each row of dataframe and add them into a dictionary.

The below code takes 18 seconds to run. The dataframe has about 150000 rows. vehicledid and engineconfigid are numerical values.

```
engineconfigid = {}
for index, row in data_engineconfig.iterrows():
    engineconfigid.update({row['vehicleid-h']:row['engineconfigid-h']})
```

However, the following code takes hours. The only difference is that there are more values to add and some of the values are strings. What accounts for bulk of the difference between the two lines? The strings are not big. My program runs at 20% CPU (single core) and only uses 60MB RAM.

```
for index, row in data_enginebase.iterrows():
        enginebase.update({row['enginebaseid-f']:{'liter':row['liter-f'],
                                                 'cc':row['cc-f'],'cid':row['cid-f'],
                                                 'cylinders-f':row['cylinders-f']}})
```

Comment: Please add a sample data in your question. I can't check if my answer is correct or not without that.

Comment: Im pretty sure there is a vectorized solution to your problem. Iterating is usually much slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `set_index`. Rather than iterating over rows, this should give better result:

```
# answer 1
engineconfigid = data_engineconfig.set_index('vehicleid-h')['engineconfigid-h'].to_dict()

# answer 2
data_engineconfig.to_dict(orient='index')
```

Comment: Awesome! Your answer #1 finished in 0.065 seconds. I cannot believe there is such a big difference. I guess I have to be careful when programming in the future.

Comment: Glad, I could help.